# Drawing cube from rectangle in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have the co-ordinates of a rectangle. How can I draw a cube with this in C#?

```
graphics.drawRectangle(Pens.Black, x, y, width, height);
```

Rectangle has four co-ordinates but a cube has 8 co-ordinates. How can I locate the other four points of the rectangle to make it look like a cube.

When drawing a cube by hand from a rectangle, we need three-dimensions `length X width X height`. We will use an angle of `60 to 70 degree (approx)` from X axis to draw z-axis and it will look like 3D. Similarly, we can draw length dimension for the rectangle and locate the point (x',y') for second rectangle. We will use the same height and width for the second rectangle and joining the two rectangles will give the cube.

I'm trying to do this in C#. To do this I need a co-ordinate of the second rectangle which is at an arbitrary distance (say 50) at an angle of 70 degree (approx) from (x, y) of first rectangle

Comment: There's no way a rectangle could turn into a cube, at least from where I see it. Do you mean a parallelepiped ?  And to turn it into a 3D form, you'll need to add  3rd dimension, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you need a cube then you can draw 2 rectangle in different co-ordinate and connect them with line. school level concept as you draw using pen and paper.

Comment: @Bartdude, Thanks for your reply. I'll edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Rezoan, This is what I'm asking, how can I calculate the co-ordinates of the second rectangle?

Comment: make the 2 rectangle size same. Now draw first rectangle and and then draw the second rectangle by increasing the Y coordinate and decreasing the X coordinate of first rectangle. size and point depends on you that how you want to look it like.

Comment: Could you not use basic trigonometry to calculate where the top right vertex of one rectangle is relative to the top right of the other (since you know the angle you want and the length of the joining line, i.e. the hypotenuse), draw your two rectangles and then calculate the relative positions of the other vertices and connect them with lines? It's not pretty but it isn't hard if you wanted to avoid the (very nice looking) GDI example @Erno de Weerd links below.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys, I found a way to locate the points of the second rectangle and drawing the cube

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to draw a cube but a rectangle will always be a rectangle. You cannot add points to it (it would not be a rectangle anymore).

Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/drawing/article.php/c8185/Create-a-3D-Cube-Structure-for-GDI.htm)
It shows you one way to draw a cube.

If you are willing to have a less sophisticated way you might transform (skew) 2 or 3 rectangles and turn them into a projection of a cube.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cheap hack for a filled cube (not wireframe), you can modify the way the 'i' part works to change the "perspective"

```
//draw the sides of the cube black
for (int i=-10;x<0;i++)
     graphics.drawRectangle(Pens.Black, x+i, y+i, width, height);
//draw the front of the cube red
graphics.fillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x, y, width, height);
```